# Golang tool for git pull?

Tags: github, go, git-pull

I'm trying to make it easy for the not-too-technical to use my golang program as a command line application. I want them to be able to update the code easily too when I push changes to github. Is there a way to update a library using something like "go update github.com/user/repo" so they don't have to cd to the src directory and git pull themselves? Or at this point must I simply say "time to learn git"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

`go get -u import/path`

> The -u flag instructs get to use the network to update the named packages
>   and their dependencies.  By default, get uses the network to check out
>   missing packages but does not use it to look for updates to existing packages.

Comment: Using the -d flag will cause the updated package not to install, so the user will effectively still be using the older version, which is the opposite of what he wants. Only the -u flag is needed.

Comment: @Marc: oh you're right. I was thinking that after he mentioned using `git pull`, that he didn't want it installed.